# How to set PYTHONSTARTUP script for Intellij/PyCharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, startupscript

I tried adding the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable:

[image]

I also tried a custom starting script:

[image]

But even more surprisingly - this **also** did not work (the `npa` alias was not recognized):

[image]

Out of a bit of desperation I even tried adding to the `interpreter options`:

[image]

That did nothing: (what actually is `Interpreter options` supposed to do .. ? )

Finally I also looked at the SDK settings for python - and also nothing available there:

[image]

So then how do we set the `PYTHONSTARTUP` script?

Comment: One should always restart pycharm after modifying the Starting script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's looking pretty unlikely that Intellij has any way to do this. Instead I have added the following to the beginning of the script

```
execfile('/Users/boescst/.pythonstartup')
```

That is for `python2` . For `python3`  it is bit different - along the lines of

```
   exec(compile(source=open('/Users/juggernaut/.pythonrc.py')
       .read(), filename=".pythonrc.py", mode="exec"))
```

Comment: py3 code example was given here as a pseudocode, I believe. so for ppl's convenience here's the exact command which worked for me: `exec(compile(source=open('/Users/juggernaut/.pythonrc.py').read(), filename=".pythonrc.py", mode="exec"))`

Comment: @juggernaut  thx for that input - i'm updating the answer with your correct code

Comment: In python 3, I add the line `import os; exec(open(os.environ["PYTHONSTARTUP"]).read())` to the Python Console Starting script.